# angular2-multiselect-dropdown not disabling select all filtered result

Tags: angular

**Html**

```
<angular2-multiselect id="multi_select" name="multiselect" required
    [disabled]="true"
    [(ngModel)]="selected"
    [data]="list" 
    (onSelect)="call()"
    (onDeSelect)="call()" [settings]="dropDownSetting" 
    (onSelectAll)="call()" 
    (onDeSelectAll)="call()">
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span>
</angular2-multiselect>
```

**TS**

```
mySettings = {
        singleSelection: false,
        text: '',
        selectAllText: 'Select All',
        unSelectAllText: 'UnSelect All',
        enableSearchFilter: true,
        badgeShowLimit: 1,
    };
```

I am not able to apply the function call in "Select all filtered result" or not able to disable it. But same is working with "Select All".

Comment: <angular2-multiselect id="multi_select" [(ngModel)]="selected" [data]="list" (onSelect)="call()"
        (onDeSelect)="call()" [settings]="dropDownSetting" name="multiselect" required
        [disabled]="true" (onSelectAll)="call()" (onDeSelectAll)="call()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-filter"></span></angular2-multiselect>

Comment: please edit your question and put the code in the content and not in the comments

Comment: The html code was already in the contents, it was a formatting issue.

Comment: I don't see a link between your TS mySettings variable and your HTML code. I suspect you want to replace the "dropDownSetting" variable in your HTML with "mySettings" ?

Comment: yes. it is actually mySettings.

Answer (score 2):

In you dropdown Settings:

```
this.dropdownSettings = {
    singleSelection: true,
    idField: 'item_id',
    textField: 'item_text',
    itemsShowLimit: 3,
    allowSearchFilter: false,
  };
```

> singleSelection: true,

Answer (score 0):

Is your question **"How do I disable selection of disabled items when I "*select all*" in [AngularJS Dropdown Multiselect](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/)?**

You have to modify the `angularjs-dropdown-multiselect.min.js` file (I use the minified file), which you would have downloaded to use this... what do you call these... thing.

The `selectAll()` function must be changed to only select the non-disabled items.

```
            function selectAll() {
               $scope.deselectAll(true);
               $scope.externalEvents.onSelectAll();

               var searchResult = $filter('filter')($scope.options, $scope.getFilter($scope.input.searchFilter));
               var filteredResult = searchResult.filter(function (option) {
                  return !option.disabled;
               });

               angular.forEach(filteredResult, function(value) {
                  $scope.setSelectedItem(value, true, false);
               });
               $scope.externalEvents.onSelectionChanged();
               $scope.selectedGroup = null;
           }
```

Source: https://github.com/dotansimha/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/issues/361